# QML - how can I get comboBox.currentText from another component?

Tags: combobox, qml, components, embedded

I just started learning qml and have a question on how to get the comboBox.currentText from another component.

code example:

```js
App {
    id: app
    width: px(250); height: px(250)

    NavigationStack {
        Page {
            id: page
            navigationBarHidden: true
            AppText { text: "startpage" }
            SimpleButton{
                x: 220; y: 0; onClicked: page.navigationStack.push(settingsPage)
            }
            AppText {
                x: 0; y: 50; text: "text " + comboBox1.currentText
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: settingsPage
        Page {
          navigationBarHidden: true
          AppText { text: qsTr("settings page") }
          SimpleButton{
              x: 220; y: 0; onClicked: page.navigationStack.push(lastPage)
          }

          ComboBox {
              id: comboBox1
              currentIndex: 0
              x: 10; y: 40
              style: ComboBoxStyle {
                  label: Text {
                      text: control.currentText
                  }
              }
              model: ListModel {
                  ListElement { text: "green" }
                  ListElement { text: "dark-green" }
                  ListElement { text: "blue" }
              }
          }

          AppText {
              x: 0; y: 90; text: "text " + comboBox1.currentText
          }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: lastPage
        Page {
          navigationBarHidden: true
          AppText { text: qsTr("last page") }
          SimpleButton{
              x: 220; y: 0; onClicked: page.navigationStack.push(page)
          }
          AppText {
              x: px(50); y: px(90); text: "text " + comboBox1.currentText
          }
       }
    }
}
```

-> I need to get the selected Listelement from the Combobox in settingspage and use it in the component with id: lastPage

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's a difference between declarative (QML) and imperative (your question) paradigm. Actually you haven't _get_ some value from some component. You have to _declare_ what should happen if this value changes. This is also where the term 'scope' comes into play. In your case I would declare a signal, probably in some root/main item that can access both the components and then fire the event from one of component and so in the signal's handler change another one.

Comment: @folibis
thank you for your quick answer. currently all my code is in a main.qml code. should I change this? I know this is a really basic question but I not entirely sure on how to structure this. do you have any examples I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have no clue what are elements you are using here (App, NavigationStack etc.) but in general the struct can be like the following:

```js
Window {
    visible: true   
    width: 400
    height: 300
    id: root
    property color someColor: "green"

    Row {
        id: element1
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: root.someColor
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: element2
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "yellow"
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    root.someColor = "blue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `element1` depends on some property from its parent/top item that always in the scope. This construction called `property bindings` in QML and can be done in several way (for example using [Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html), good for dynamic elements ).  The `element2` also can access/change the property and so changing it from `element2` immediately affects `element1`. That also solves an issue when you want to access  `element1` from the `root` and `element1` not in scope, or not exists or whatever else that will crash you application in this case.

Comment: `Window` doesn't matter here, I just wanted to show the concept, a working example